# How to store entire mysql_fetch_array results into an array? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have one SQL query and the results are retrieved using;

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

And the results are printed using;

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['column']."<br>";
}
```

I want to store entire `$row['column']` into an array. For that, the above code can be replaced by;

```
$my_array[] = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['column']."<br>";
    $my_array[] = $row['column'];
}
```

But here, the while loop is executed. Is there any other efficient / better method, avoiding loops?

Comment: Why don't you just read the desired column only and you have it in the array? All you need to do is select your desired column in the query.

Comment: why -1? isnt my question clear?

Comment: @itsols is this problem related to a select query? well, I dont think so

Comment: Of course your question is clear. Why -1, even I don't know. I think there are a few people who can't negotiate between their thoughts and the mouse they use. I wish there is a system to reveal who does these down-votes. It wasn't me.

Comment: My question to you is why not just do a query like `select column from table`? This way, you already have it in an array. Of course it's going to be an associate array.

Comment: @itsols you're right. seems like the guy had a rethought, downvote is gone

Comment: @itsols I do have a query like it. But is that variable an array? when I echo my query, it gives `Resource id #5`

Comment: `But here, the while loop is executed again` How so?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I mean, in the second situation also, i have to depend on while loop

Comment: There is no escape from that using `mysql_*` api. You have to use that loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store your desired value in your array right there in the first loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['column']."<br>";
    $my_array[] = $row['column'];
}
```

Now you don't need 2 loops. `$my_array` is available to you to use anywhere you like

> But here, the while loop is executed again

No, absolutely incorrect. This can be done in just 1 loop call and loop is not executed again.

> But here, the while loop is executed. Is there any other efficient / better method, avoiding loops?

Nope there is none using `mysql_*` but yes using `mysqli` or `pdo` you can fetch all rows in an array using just one call without any loops.

> How can I do that using mysqli_* can u include that in your answer

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$query = "SELECT column FROM yourTable";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$my_array = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you include the element number to hold the value in `$my_array`?

Comment: No, I have only one loop, i just avoided the echo part.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Can I avoid that loop? Thats what i am asking

Comment: Nope you can't with `mysql_*`. See my last line of the edited answer

Comment: How can I do that using `mysqli_*` can u include that in your answer? I mean, the code